# How can I tell if a value is a string or a list in Django templates?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I've got a tuple of values I'm iterating in a Django template (1.4). Some of the values are strings which must just print out, others are tuples containing strings, which must be iterated themselves to print out their values. Is there a way, within the template, that I can decide if a given value, as I iterate over the master tuple, is a string or a list (tuple) ?

Comment: `if isinstance(val, list) ... else ...` should work

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony: not inside a Django template

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony : also it's better to test against basestring - usually for this class of problems you want to know if it's a string or any other kind of sequence.

Comment: sorry, missed the template part!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no builtin way to do so. A (somewhat dirty IMHO) workaround would be to implement a custom "is_string" filter, but the best solution would be to preprocess the values in the view to make it an uniform list of tuples (or list).

for the filter solution:

```
@register.filter
def is_string(val):
    return isinstance(val, basestring)
```

and then in your templates:

```
<ul> 
{% for whatever in something %}
  <li>
    {% if whatever|is_string %} 
      {{ whatever }}
    {% else %}
    <ul>
      {{ whatever|unordered_list }}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

cf the excellent Django doc for more on custom filters and templatetags:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 6):

You can create an `isinstance` filter in the view or a helper module:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import register

@register.filter(name="isinstance")
def isinstance_filter(val, instance_type):
    return isinstance(val, eval(instance_type))
```

Then in the template you could do:

```
{% load isinstance %}
{% if some_value|isinstance:"list" %}
  // iterate over list
{% else %}
  // use string
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The 'eval' here is a big no-no - it's costly, and it's a potential security issue. This will not pass a code review here.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: It could be made faster, but how is it a security issue?

Comment: @Blender  try this: `{% if some_value|isintance:"os.system('rm -rf ./')" %}`
Of course you wouldn't write this, but if anyone manage to pass untrusted input to `eval`... well, I think you get the point

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: What's the alternative then? `__builtins__[instance_type]`? A whitelist? I get that `eval` is a *potential* security risk, but why in the world would anybody pass it user input in this scenario?

Comment: @Blender the real solution is to either know what (kind of) values you're sending to your template OR pass values that either know how to display themselves (or at least gives the template the required infos about themselves). As to why would anybody pass raw user inputs to a template filter, did you ever wonder why some sites still have sql injections vulnerabilities ?